# What is the difference between -all and ~all in a DNS SPF record?

Tags: domain-name-system, spf

I've found that our current DNS SPF record uses the `~all` keyword, but in most examples I've seen `-all` used.

What's the difference between the two?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The tilde and dash identify they different types of failures.  Consider a message that doesn't match the parameters specified in the SPF record.  Tilde is for a softfail, the message will be accepted and marked if it doesn't match parameters specified.  Dash is for a hardfail, the message will be rejected if it doesn't match.

more info here: [support.microsoft.com/kb/2640313](http://web.archive.org/web/20150110222911/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2640313)

Comment: The link you provided is broken.

Comment: Replaced the broken link with a web archive copy. Very useful article by the way!